Forward end of a url after slash via proxy pass nginx
I have the following snippet where I'm trying to take everything after my slash and send it to a remote server.
so its something like:
mydomain.example.com/https://newserver.example.com
and i want to make a request (https://newserver.example.com) to the new server.
Is there anything I'm doing obviously wrong here?
location ~ ^/(http[s]?:/.*) {
                proxy_pass \$1;  # Ensures correct URL formation
                proxy_set_header Host \$host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP \$remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto \$scheme;
                proxy_read_timeout 600s;
                proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
                proxy_send_timeout 600s;
                proxy_ssl_verify off;
            }

Quick edit: I am using CAT to write this in a larger cloud init file, so I believe the \$ is necessary.
